# how to separate two regexp (for taking text from brackets in commented area)?

Tags: regex

I have some html page, it looks like:

```
<span>Some text</span>
<p>And again</p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text [some text]</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <!--[content-->
        <tr>
            <td>again some txt but with [this]</td>
            <td>in this td the same situation [oops]</td>
            <td>hello [world]</td>
        </tr>
        <!--content]-->
    </tbody>
</table>

<span>here is [the text]</span>
```

I need to take text from square brackets, but just in commented fields. I have 2 reg exp and they are work fine, but separately.

```
/[^[\]]+(?=])/g - this is for text in brackets;
(?=<!--\[content)([\s\S]*?content]-->) - for commented fields.
```

But I can't combine it. I was trying this `(?=<!--\[content)([^[\]]+(?=]))([\s\S]*?content]-->)` but it's not works. I don't know much regexp, how can I combine it?

UPD: for output I need text in brackets only between commented fields (this, oops, world).

Comment: What exactly output do you want? Please write it down as "Expected output" in code format.

Comment: @fronthem sorry, I fix question

Comment: So, is that JavaScript? I think your approach is good enough. Match the comment first, then collect all the words inside brackets. ES5 regex flavor does not allow you to use `\G` operator that comes handy in such scenarios.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I understand, I just think that this 2 regexp can be combine with each other)

Comment: Yes, [they can, sure, but do you really want **this**](https://regex101.com/r/zZ7zI5/1)? Or the one below - I doubt it will be readable and maintainable for the majority of developers.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I guess you are right, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I might start from some simple one:

```
(?<=\[)[^\]\[]*(?=\])(?=[\s\S]*?<!--content\]-->)
```

**Explanation**

`(?<=\[)[^\]\[]*(?=\])` match text inside any square brackets,

`(?=[\s\S]*?<!--content\]-->)` lookahead to any string that followed by a closed content tag.

Its sound so make sense right! **BUT** anyway, check this out [DEMO1](https://regex101.com/r/vG6jX5/1). yeah...it didn't work. So, the question is why???

In the regex above there is still some problem about the lookahead assertion, as I mentioned before in the previous explanation:

`(?=[\s\S]*?<!--content\]-->)` lookahead to any string that **followed by a closed content tag**.

This is **WRONG**, it should be:

`(?=[\s\S]*?<!--content\]-->)` lookahead to any string that **followed by any open or closed content tags**.

So, the conclusion our issue is the regex `[\s\S]*?` sometimes it just matches "more than one content tags".

**Workaround**

To prevent the above issue, we can put another negative lookaheads of the open content tags to be coupled with every characters that will be generated by `[\s\S]*`. Thus, we get:

```
(?<=\[)[^\]\[]*(?=\])(?=(?:(?!<!--\[content-->)[\s\S])*?<!--content\]-->)
```

Notice that

```
[\s\S]*
```

is just modified to

```
(?:(?!<!--\[content-->)[\s\S])*?
```

which means `(?!<!--\[content-->)` is spawned to be in front of every characters that generated by `[\s\S]*`. For example if `[\s\S]*` generates `ABCDEF...`, the negative lookahead will be spawned in this way:

```
(?!<!--\[content-->)A(?!<!--\[content-->)B(?!<!--\[content-->)C(?!<!--\[content-->)D(?!<!--\[content-->)E(?!<!--\[content-->)F...
```

Finally, please check the [DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/cW9eV8/1). See that right? it's just work!

**DISCLAIMER:** My regex here will be work fine under only the simple examples that you were provided on the question. For the another complex such as some recursive structure, I can not guarantee that.